How to access transaction data in Alastria networks?
I have read an article about a personal data leak on Alastria networks: https://medium.com/@4k-research/personal-data-leak-alastria-blockchain-ecosystem-9366544d1cd9. Following the article idea I have found nodes in both T and B Networks of Alastria with open RPC ports. For example I tryed:
telnet 18.100.18.26 22000

and
telnet 34.249.11.251 8545

and could connect to both.
But how can I use this connection to get the data for specific transactions? For example transactions 0x0001ea67418bf097ce1e9b1bfc3e173fd21012c7bb22f024ef9627ae1bd4386a and 0x7f3d4703e53c53090c51a8278d650458bde55fe266a5cb4e68ab8aa515b2e97f in T Network (this should contain personal data of Iberdrola shareholders), or transactions 0x50d904947df48a92cb6841dae306f5c298e54d29fe6a878254856431c3543927 and 0x819871fedda45692c5ba28ba266ca0caefb23a5a64f484c40a9c2bfb9b373d75 in B Network (should contain documents full of personal data).
Is there any easier way to read transactions from nodes with open RPC ports?
If it helps, in its github Alastria says B Network is running Besu nodes and T Network running GoQuorum nodes.
